# Eureka form, TextAreaRow scroll to bottom

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Can I configure a TextAreaRow of an Eureka form to scroll to bottom?
I am appending text to the TextAreaRow and would like to show the newly appended text.

Comment: Can you post what you have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextAreaRow in Eureka is essentially an UITextView

You can simply use UITextView's `scrollRangeToVisible(_ range: NSRange)` function in its cell setup and onchange blocks.

So here's an example how you can use it.

```
<<< TextAreaRow("") { row in
        //Row setup

    }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
         cell.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(cell.textView.text.characters.count - 1, 1))
    }).onChange({ (row) in
         //Your Change logic

         row.cell.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(row.cell.textView.text.characters.count - 1, 1))
    })
```